# MySQL how do I priorities single column by multiple keywords

Tags: mysql, query, php

I have a column of product title, I have to order by result by max word's matched from entered string

```
Select Id, tittle, description,.....,
Case 
When a.title REGEXP [[:<:]]Men's shoes[[:>:]] Then 0
When a.title REGEXP [[:<:]]Men's[[:>:]] Then 1
When a.title REGEXP [[:<:]]shoes[[:>:]] Then 2 END AS priority
From products 
.
.
.

Order by priority ASC
```

It's work fine, when string come in order, but I want order by max matched word count,
or assigned first priority to that record which have max word matches

Comment: have you tried a full text index?

Comment: No I haven't tried with full text index

Comment: so add a fulltext index and try matching for all three or more words and see what weight it shows you, it it not help remove it again

Comment: nothing change getting same results

Comment: please make a [mre] so we can see

Comment: Be careful using the `[[:<:]]` regexp pattern. It is not supported in MySQL 8.0, they changed the regexp implementation and now they use `\b` for both start and end word boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full text searches have their good site, but need a bit of learning, but are interesting for big tables with alot of text.

you can combine columns also for searches

Also check the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

A small example how it works

> ```
> CREATE TABLe t1 (title varchar(20),
>           FULLTEXT (title))
> ```

> ```
> insert into t1 VALUES ("men\'s t'shirts"),("men\'s socks"),("men\'s socks short")
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * ,
> (IF(MATCH (title)
>         AGAINST ("men\'s" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) > 0,1,0) 
>         )+
>         (IF(MATCH (title)
>         AGAINST ('socks' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) > 0,2,0) )
> +
>         (IF(MATCH (title)
>         AGAINST ("+men\'s +socks" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) > 0.03,3,0))    as weight   
>         FROM t1
> ```

> ```
> title             | weight
> :---------------- | -----:
> men's t'shirts    |      1
> men's socks       |      6
> men's socks short |      6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0255c3a009a38311c03e9876e3d721e7)*
For much bigger searches and more possibilities, you could also look into [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co)

Comment: Thanks for the help I will implement this and update here

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN a.title REGEXP 'least priority pattern'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        +CASE WHEN a.title REGEXP 'next priority pattern'     THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
        +CASE WHEN a.title REGEXP 'more priority pattern'     THEN 4 ELSE 0 END
        +CASE WHEN a.title REGEXP 'greatest priority pattern' THEN 8 ELSE 0 END DESC
```

Of course relative weights may be not 1-2-4-8 but any which gives the most adequate sorting.